# React Component wont render in Codepen

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, codepen

I have a simple radio button group component [on codepen here](https://codepen.io/canovice/pen/PRrKqv?editors=0010) that is not rendering in codepen. I want to post this to the code review stackexchange, since it is one of the first components i've built and will be necessary in many places on a web app I am building. However for that post, I want my codepen example to be working.

I think I am probably breaking some rule about how to use es6 in react to get the app to render, but I am struggling to debug. My console.logs() are not helping, and the error messages in codepen arent helping a ton either.

Since I linked to my codepen, I have to accompany it with code, so here's what I have in my codepen at the moment:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ToggleButton, ToggleButtonGroup } from 'react-bootstrap';


class ToolButtonGroup extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    };
  
    render() {

        // Get Variables from the params prop
        const { header, buttons, initialVal } = this.props.params;
        const { borderRadius, margin, padding, fontsize, border } = this.props.params;
        const { gridID, gridColumns, minRowHeight } = this.props.params;

        // Create the individual buttons
        const pageButtons = buttons.map((buttoninfo, idx) => {
            return (
                <ToggleButton 
                    key={idx}
                    style={{
                        "borderRadius": borderRadius, 
                        "margin": margin,
                        "padding": padding,
                        "fontSize": fontsize,
                        "border": border
                    }}
                    bsSize="large"
                    value={buttoninfo.value}>
                {buttoninfo.label}
                </ToggleButton>
            )
        })

        // Return the button group
        return(
            <div 
              style={{"border": "1px solid red" }} 
              id={gridID}>
                <h2 style={{
                  "width": "100%",
                  "margin": "0 auto",
                  "fontSize": "1.75em",
                  "marginTop": "5px",   
                  "border": "none"
                }}
                >{header}</h2>
                <ToggleButtonGroup 
                    type="radio"
                    name="charttype-options" 
                    defaultValue={initialVal} 
                    onChange={this.props.handler}
                    style={{
                        "display": "grid",
                        "gridTemplateColumns": "repeat(" + gridColumns + ", 1fr)",
                        "gridAutoRows": "auto",
                        "gridGap": "8px"
                    }}
                >
                    {pageButtons}
                </ToggleButtonGroup>
            </div>
        )
    }   
}



class StarterApp extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            pitchersOrHitters: "",
            position: ""
        }
    }

    // Button and Select Handlers!
    handlePitchHitChange = (pitchersOrHitters) => {
        this.setState({pitchersOrHitters})
    }
    handlePositionChange = (position) => {
        this.setState({ position: position });
    }

    render() {

        console.log("A")
        // 0. Load State and Props 
        const { pitchersOrHitters, position } = this.state;


        // Pitcher or Hitter Radio Button Group params
        const pitchOrHitButtonGroup = {
            borderRadius: "25px",
            margin: "1% 10%",
            padding: "5%",
            fontsize: "2em",
            border: "2px solid #BBB",

            gridColumns: 1, minRowHeight: "10px", "gridID": "buttons1",

            header: "Choose One:",          
            buttons: [
                { value: "Pitchers", label: "Pitchers" },
                { value: "Hitters", label: "Hitters" },
            ],
            initialVal: "Pitchers"}

        // Pitcher or Hitter Radio Button Group params
        const positionButtonGroup = {
            borderRadius: "10px",
            margin: "1% 10%",
            padding: "5%",
            fontsize: "1.25em",
            border: "2px solid #BBB",

            gridColumns: 4, minRowHeight: "20px", "gridID": "buttons2",

            header: "Choose One:",          
            buttons: [
                { value: "SP", label: "SP" },
                { value: "RP", label: "RP" },
                { value: "1B", label: "1B" },
                { value: "2B", label: "2B" },
                { value: "SS", label: "SS" },
                { value: "3B", label: "3B" },
                { value: "LF", label: "LF" },
                { value: "RF", label: "RF" },
                { value: "CF", label: "CF" }
            ],
            initialVal: "SP"}

        return(
            <div className="chart-grid-container">
                <ToolButtonGroup
                    params={pitchOrHitButtonGroup}
                    value={pitchersOrHitters}
                    handler={this.handlePitchHitChange} />    

                <ToolButtonGroup
                    params={positionButtonGroup}
                    value={position}
                    handler={this.handlePositionChange} />    
            </div>
        )
    }
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <StarterApp />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```css
.chart-grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
    grid-auto-rows: minmax(200px, auto);
    grid-gap: 5px;
    grid-template-areas:
        "btns1 btns1 btns2 btns2 btns2 btns2 . . . . . .";
}

#buttons1 { grid-area: btns1; }  
#buttons2 { grid-area: btns2; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.1/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.1/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'>
  COME ON WORK!
</div>
```

**Im unsurprisingly struggling to get this code snippet working as well.** Although in this case, it is because I don't know how to include react-bootstrap, which is something I've already done in my codepen.

Thanks!

Comment: You are importing ToggleButtonGroup and then create a class again, why? Also, do not create functions in your render block. If you need functions do it outside of render. Also, I suggest using codesandbox.io or stackblitz.com to try React components. You can add dependencies easily on this platforms.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed I got the errors when using `import` statements on that specific project.

This is probably a limitation of transpiling engine on the codepen. Better if you use some platform (ie: [enter link description here](http://codesandbox.io)) that already has all of these solved out for you.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/pml29zl6jm) is your code on codesandbox.
[image]

Comment: thanks. i dont understand what the codepen limitation is though? i added the required packages (react, react-bootstrap, react-dom) and all. oh well, i'll use this